# Factory_Girl rake issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, factory-bot

I'm creating a new Rails 3.1 application using Cucumber, Devise, and Factory_Girl. I installed successfully Devise and Cucumber. I then created the spec/factories.rb file that contains the following:

```
require 'factory_girl'

Factory.define :user do |user|
  user.name 'Test User'
  user.email 'test@email.com'
  user.password' testpass'
end
```

I also added spec/support/devise.rb to add in the test hooks for Devise:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
end
```

In regards to testing, I have not touched anything else and now everytime I run any rake command I get the following (I ran rake spec in this case, just to make sure everything is ready for tests):

```
rake aborted!
Factory already registered: user

Tasks: TOP => spec => db:test:prepare => db:abort_if_pending_migrations => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Now if I remove the Factory.define block from the factories file, it runs fine. I've done some Google searching and have come up with absolutely nothing. Since it's saying the Factory is already registered, is Devise for whatever reason, creating a factory already?

Comment: I don't use Devise personally, but I know it calls the user model `User`, so it's probably a fair assumption that that's the case; Devise is already registering a user factory.

Comment: I also forgot to add that I did run db:migrate right after installing Devise. I ran that on both the development and test database. There's also no outstanding migrations from what I could tell (since there's only one).

Comment: Did you try removing the Devise TestHelpers to see if that makes the error go away?

Comment: Removing the TestHelpers does not make the error go away. I'll go ahead and see if I can use the factory without defining it. Just to see if Devise is creating one already.

Comment: The factory was auto-generated somewhere, so I don't have to define it. Thanks guys!